# SSRS Parameter locations are not setting properly in the Preview tab

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools

SQL Server 2014

Visual Studio 2017

SSDT 15.1.6.61804.210

SSRS 14.0.1016.268

I am creating an SSRS report in Visual Studio (not Report Builder) and the report parameters in the Design tab have been set to be next to each other (in logical order). Unfortunately, the last parameter is being wrapped to the second row, which should not be the case (see screenshot image links below). I do not believe the parameter field widths are causing them to be wrapped to the second row.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

https://postimg.cc/image/9hfo5beht/
https://postimg.cc/image/460rkm04x/

Comment: You cannot have more than 2 parameter "columns" in SSRS 2014, in SSRS 2016 you have the option to set a custom layout for parameters which since you're using VS2017  it is showing you this option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have more than 2 parameter "columns" in SSRS 2014, in SSRS 2016 you have the option to set a custom layout for parameters which since you're using VS 2017 it is showing you this option but you may not use it since you're going to deploy to ssrs 2014.

Comment: That also explains the warning that I was getting: `Custom parameter layout was removed from the report. SQL Server 2014 Reporting Services and earlier do not support custom parameter layout.` It is odd that VS 2017 would do that considering Server Targeting is now allowed. Note: SSIS adds and removes components based on which Server is being targeted.. Thanks for pointing that out.